# Angular & Golang "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin is presents..."

Tags: angular, go, jwt

I am using Angular to build a front-end GUI app to interact with my API server written in Go.

I've tried adding the header on both ends, client and the server, yet no luck. I've tried disabling the http interceptor, so it doesn't add the JWT token in which case I get the unauthorized access error, which is expected. But wherever I add the token to the request (either with the interceptor or manually before making the get request) the unauthorized access error is gone (so far so good), but then the missing header error appears. The server should return JSON data of stored articles, and it works with Postman and my other vanilla JS front-end.

Go code:

```
r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  http.ServeFile(w, r, "./index.html")
})

allowedHeaders := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With"})
allowedOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
allowedMethods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})

r.HandleFunc("/login", GetTokenHandler).Methods("POST")

apiRouter := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
apiRouter.Use(jwtMiddleware.Handler)
apiRouter.HandleFunc("/articles", getArticles).Methods("GET")
apiRouter.HandleFunc("/articles/{id}", getArticle).Methods("GET")
apiRouter.HandleFunc("/articles", createArticle).Methods("POST")
apiRouter.HandleFunc("/articles/{id}", updateArticle).Methods("PUT")
apiRouter.HandleFunc("/articles/{id}", deleteArticle).Methods("DELETE")
fmt.Println("Server running on port", port)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, handlers.CORS(allowedHeaders, allowedOrigins, allowedMethods)(r)))
```

Angular get request:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/articles')
.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
},
err => console.log(err));
```

Angular HttpInterceptor:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (token) {
            const cloned = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            });

            return next.handle(cloned);
        }
        else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

... request.. has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Edit: Go imports:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"

    jwtmiddleware "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
```

Comment: I fail to see in the question, what package are you using for those "routers" and middleware stuff.

Comment: I added the packages which are imported in my Go API to the question, on the Angular side I am using HttpClient, HttpHeaders.. etc from @angular/common/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is known as **CORS**. **C**ross **O**rigin **R**esource **S**haring. This is arises when the origin of the request and response is different. For example: If your project is on **https://139.43.33.122:1111/** and your server is hosted on **https://123.0.3.444:3000**, then the origin of your request and response are completely different and thus, browser will block the response. This is the browser thing. Postman doesn't care about their origin. To receive response, there are 2 ways (maybe more but i use these 2 only).

1. **Additional Headers:** If yoou have access/permission to server code, then add an additional header to the server responses: 
   **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type**.
2. **Use Extensions:** There are multiple extensions that can bypass this restriction. IF you do not have access or permission to change the server response, then this is the way to go.I'm personally using this method only.

Answer (score 1):

Following things will help you resolve this issue:

1) Since you are including **Authorization** as well in the request header, allow the same in the server which seems to be missed.

2) You can use Proxy.config to map to the desired host ( hostname + port)
  a) Create proxy.config.json file :

```
{
  "/api/articles": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

b) run via following command :

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

[Refer This To Setup Proxy](https://medium.com/@spencerfeng/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

try these things first.